# What is the score range of Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

when we use an emotion api in Microsoft cognitive services in post request it will return the emotion scores as JSON file like below

```
"scores": {
  "anger": 9.075572e-13,
  "contempt": 7.048959e-9,
  "disgust": 1.02152783e-11,
  "fear": 1.778957e-14,
  "happiness": 0.9999999,
  "neutral": 1.31694478e-7,
  "sadness": 6.04054263e-12,
  "surprise": 3.92249462e-11
}
```

how to use these scores.i.e on which scale we want to use these scores so that we can represent it in a graph.
example: fear score is :1.778957e-14 out of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scale is [0,1.0]

So in your example the most likely emotion predicted is "happiness"

Comment: thanks ,it is very usefull for my application Ryan Galgon

Comment: Thanks [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388344/ryan-galgon) for letting us know the scoring `min` and `max` values. Is this written on the API docs somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

try casting another type, or convert to string like `score.Happines.ToString("0.000000")`